# why does the Breaker trip randomly with no load

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have A 15 amp beaker at the panel that randomly trips. The breaker controls the line to the detached garage, where it runs to a two 15 amp fuse box. The wiring is underground rated burial cable. The fuses don't blow, the breaker just trips. I have removed all switches and outlets to the fuse panel and I have replaced the breaker.

I have power running to the fuse panel and nothing else. The voltage at the fuse panel is registering 122 volts. The breaker will trip when it wants with no apparent load draw. Is it safe to assume I have a short between the main panel and the fuse box in the garage?

I have lived here for 45 yrs and don't know how long before I moved here when the cable was run.

Comment: Could be the age of the breaker, it is getting weaker and trips at less than rated range, or a problem with the cable/wires.  Might be a nice time to upgrade the breaker and wires, maybe to 20 or more amps, depending if you do any work in the garage, or just have lights.

Comment: Is this a plain breaker or is it a AFCI or GFCI breaker?

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: A little formatting, using the American (and British) customary "period" `.` instead of a "comma" `,` between sentences. Some capitalization and all of a sudden, it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

That's a long time for direct bury cable (not in conduit?)  Do you have moles?  Could be it was damaged by moles or gophers (cue up Bill Murry from CaddyShack).

Next, like @crip659 said, the supplying breaker may be getting tired. What brand panel?  Has it been upgraded in the past 45 years?

If you are comfortable (AND CAREFUL) working inside a live panel, I'd ordinarily suggest getting a meter with an amp clamp, put it around the hot supplying the detached structure and see if it's drawing any power at all with everything turned off in the garage.  If it is, you have a problem with the buried cable or the wiring in the garage. Obviously you can't sit there all day watching an amp clamp meter waiting for the breaker to trip.  So I have the following suggestions:

1. disconnect the hot from the breaker that trips and see if it still trips randomly.
2. If possible, swap the hot from another circuit to the breaker that trips and the hot to the garage to the other breaker  you just freed up.    If the problem follows the hot to the garage, there's your clue. If the breaker that was randomly tripping continues to do so, as Jeff Foxworthy would say, there's your clue.
3. You might also try disconnecting the hot in the fuse box in the garage (with the power off to the garage! and cap it with a wire nut) and see if the problem continues, you might have a wiring problem in the garage if the breaker stops tripping. Is the wiring exposed?  Rodent damage (esp. mice) can do a lot of damage and cause shorts.  I've posted about that several times now and have experienced it personally.  That cause should not be dismissed.

One caution:  When doing this testing, if you choose to swap circuits, don't swap with anything very important: like a fridge, freezer, computer, router, etc.

Because I'm asking questions, I would have preferred to put this is a comment, rather than an answer, but I had too much to say.   Please let us know what you find.

Comment: it's a plain breaker' no test button,I replaced the original tripping breaker with a new one same make,mfg,etc and that one is tripping,There is nothing except the fuse box connected to the line,I disconnected everything that feeds out from the fuse box,it's not buried in conduit,its a square d panel,the only updates i'm aware of are a couple of breakers added by an electrician in the  early eighties.